# how to compare anova using data frame by row

Tags: r, anova

i have a df with 2 columns:

```
df <- read.table(text="   a  b
1   1 g1
2   7 g1
3   9 g1
4  15 g1
5  17 g1
6   3 g2
7   5 g2
8   9 g2
9  11 g2
10  7 g2", header=TRUE)
```

so i want to compare g1 vs g2 using the "a" columns, something like

```
aov(g1 ~ g2, data=df)
```

well it will be ok with columns, but with rows how can I do it ????

Comment: This can help: `aov(df$a[df$b=='g1']~df$a[df$b=='g2'])`

Comment: The syntax is just `aov(a ~ b, data=df)`

Comment: @Duck `aov()` doesn't work like that!

Answer (score 1):

The tilde is read "as a function of". Your comparison is: A as a function of B, rather than what you are trying: g1 "compared to" g2. The solution is:

`aov(a~b, data = df)`